# Laravel 4.1 AutoComplete Field not showing results

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete, laravel-4

Ok, so here's the exact problem that i'm having. I have this autocomplete field and whenever I type anything in it, my console shows me every single record in the table i get my results from, no matter what I type.
Below the field, a list of "results" comes up blank, no text in any of the options.
Here's my code.

**The AutoComplete Field**

```
{{ Form::text('busqueda', '', array('class'=>'ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all', 'id'=>'busqueda')) }}
```

**The jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#busqueda").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{URL('ajax/getBooksAutocomplete')}}",
                data: {
                    busqueda: this.term
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    // data must be an array containing 0 or more items
                    console.log("[SUCCESS] " + data.length + " item(s)");
                    //response(data);
                    response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                        return {
                            label: item.name,
                            value: item.id
                        };
                    }));
                },
            });
        },
    });
});
```

**The Route**

```
Route::get('ajax/getBooksAutocomplete', array('uses'=>'BookController@getBooksAutocomplete'));
```

**The Controller**

```
class BookController extends BaseController {
...
    public function getBooksAutocomplete(){
        $term = Input::get('busqueda');
        $books = array();
        $search = DB::table('books')->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%')->get();
        foreach($search as $results => $book){
            $books[] = array('id'=>$book->id, 'name'=>$book->name);
        }
        return Response::json($books);
    }
...
}
```

Any help provided will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi. i am not sure, but where you assign the returned values from the ajax like .done(function( result ) {
   // assign resilt of the ajax request
  });

Comment: well i'm not so sure of how i should do that. I've seen many examples online, but none that works perfectly for me

Comment: Just updated the jQuery section to the one that actually brings up the results. However when i click on one, the text field displays the id of the selected choice, not the name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried using id, label, value as default array key?

```
class BookController extends BaseController {
...
    public function getBooksAutocomplete(){
        $term = Input::get('busqueda');
        $books = array();
        $search = DB::table('books')->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%')->get();
        foreach($search as $results => $book){
            $books[] = array('id'=>$book->id, 'label'=>$book->name, 'value'=>$book->id);
        }
        return Response::json($books);
    }
...
}
```

this should let you use autocomplete with less code at the javascript side.

make the busqueda a hidden field to save the selected autocomplete option and buesqueda2 as the autocomplete. so when you select busqueda2, it will update the hidden input buesqueda with the selected option. so to do this, you add this to the javascript side:

```
 $("#busqueda2").autocomplete({
  ....
   select: function (event, ui) {
    $('#busqueda2').val(ui.item.label);
    $('#busqueda').val(ui.item.id);
   }
  ....
});
```

Comment: You're right, I should've done that from the beggining. That's how I do it when using Yii. However it still doesn't solve my problem.
I'm not using $.map() function anymore, i just use response(data).
The list comes up fine now. But when I choose an option, the text field displays the value, which is the id. And i need it to display the name and maybe pass the id to a hidden field so that when i save, i don't have to look for the record that has that name... specially since books.name is not a unique field in the table

Comment: i think i get the problem. take a look at my edited answer. does this solve it?

Answer (score 1):

try this, this is not ready code to copy paste, it's just an idea

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#busqueda").autocomplete(function(){
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "someFileName.pgp",
        data: "searchField="+ui.item['name'];
        }).done(function( result ) {
            $("#someElementToDispalyResult").html(result)
        });
    });
});
```

**EDIT** i see now

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#busqueda").autocomplete(function(){
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "someFileName.pgp",
        data: "searchField="+ui.item['name'];
        }).done(function( result ) {
          var options = eval('(' + result + ')');
          var length = options.length;

            for(var j = 0; j < length; j++)
            {
                var newOption = $('<option/>');
                newOption.attr('value', options[j].id);
                newOption.html( options[j].name); 
                $('#mySelect').append(newOption);
            }


        });
    });
});
```

just chage names accordingly

Comment: i tried .done(...) some time ago, when i do it just says $('#busqueda').autocomplete(...).done(...) is not a function.

Comment: done is a function of ajax , have a look precisely what i did

Comment: Oh,yeah i was doing that part wrong. It accepts the done() now, however the list still returns with empty options, and when i click on one of them nothing happens

Comment: Iget what you're trying to do now, and it SHOULD be working perfectly with that new piece of code. It still returns the result to the  console but shows an empty list. It might be a css problem or the  fact that i'm using an input field type="text".

Comment: ok i managed to do this in the success function.
response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
    return {
 label: item.name,
 value: item.id
    }
}));
Now when i select an option, the input field shows me the id, not the name. Working on it

Answer (score 1):

Check this code it works with me it's simple

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("#term").autocomplete({
          source: "{{URL('getautocomplete')}}",
          minLength: 2,
          select: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.item) {
               $("#term").val(ui.item.value);
               this.form.submit();
            }
          }
        });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: well, i asked this question months ago and i found a way that works, but i always bookmark my stackoverflow questions, so i will definitely going to try it your way. The way I see it, the shorter the code, the better. Thank you for your answer. It;s never late to learn something new :)

Comment: I am so glad, and please give me a feedback when you use the code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks zam, I managed to get to the solution like 2 minutes before I saw your edited post. It turns out the autocomplete using Laravel's Form::text() works different than with Yii's CJuiAutoComplete widget. This is my code now.

**The view:**

```
{{ Form::text('busqueda', '', array('class'=>'ui-autocomplete-input ui-widget-content ui-corner-all', 'id'=>'busqueda')) }}
{{ Form::hidden('id_busqueda', '', array('id'=>'id_busqueda')) }}
```

**The controller:**

```
class BookController extends BaseController {
...
    public function getBooksAutocomplete(){
        $term = Input::get('busqueda');
        $books = array();
        $search = DB::table('books')->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$term.'%')->get();
        foreach($search as $results => $book){
            $books[] = array('id'=>$book->id, 'value'=>$book->name);
        }
        return Response::json($books);
    }
...
}
```

**The jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#busqueda").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{URL('ajax/getBooksAutocomplete')}}",
                data: {
                    busqueda: request.term
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("[SUCCESS] " + data.length + " item(s)");
                    response(data);
                },
            });
        },
        select: function(event, ui){
            $('#id_busqueda').val(ui.item.id);
        }
    })
});
```

**The Roots of the Problem:**

1. I went through one of my Yii projects, and it turns out i DO also return an id and a value, and the value contains the part of the array that I want to show, which in this case would be the "name" of the books in the array.
2. I wasn't taking into account the fact that I'm working with a text field, in which case the value is exactly what is shown in the field, there is no way that the text in the field will be one thing and the value will be another. Before I started thinking straight, I was considering the text field as a dropdown, where the text and the value of the options are two separate things.
3. The reason why the hidden field wasn't taking the value of the chosen option was that I only passing the parameter "item" to the success function, and then putting "item.id" as the value of the hidden field. Now, I still don't understand why I have to pass the "event" parameter, but the "ui" parameter just makes sense, since ui becomes an array of arrays.